# How to get the vertices from an edge

Tags: python

I make a selection of specific edges

```
indices = [442, 443, 444, 445]
edges = [e for e in bm.edges]
ee0 = []
for vert in edges:
    if vert.index in indices:
        ee0 = ee0 + [vert]
```

No I would like to get the vertices connected to these edges
So I tried

```
verts = [v for e in ee0 if e.select for v in e.verts]
```

the result of verts is empty
How can I get the vertices connected to an edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your result is empty is because (and im assuming) your not selecting the vertices

Remove the if e.select

```
verts = [v for e in ee0 for v in e.verts]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Code edit**

*To the questioner,  Please ignore this answer.: it is for **others** who may come across this question / answer after code to get bmesh elements from their indices, or for those like me who cannot see "not nice" code with out suggesting alteration.  Rather than long-commenting added here as an alternate answer.*

If we have the indices of vertices  can look them up via `bm.verts[index]`, after calling `bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()`  to ensure the indexing.  Similarly for edges and faces.  Need only loop over indices.

```
[bm.edges[i] for i in edge_indices]
```

Looping over every vertex and checking `if v.index == index` or worse `if v.index in indices`, then appending with `verts = verts + [v]` (suggest `verts.append(v)`) is both grossly inefficient and s shown, not required.

Use a set for verts in edges to have only one occurrence of each vert.  There will be same vert added to list for each connected edge in the list comprehension. Cast it back to a list if need be.  `list(set(verts))`

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

edge_indices = [0, 2, 4]
bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()

edges = [bm.edges[i] for i in edge_indices]

all_verts_in_edges = set(v for e in edges for v in e.verts)

print(edges)
print(all_verts_in_edges)
```